# Has austerity caused the death of over 130,000 people in the UK?

Tags: economics, mortality, united-kingdom

On BBC Question Time, Thursday 13 June 2019, Francesca Martinez said:

> Austerity has caused the death of over 130,000 human beings in Britain. That is absolutely outrageous. That is 130,000 mums and dads, sons and daughters, aunts and uncles who have died because the Tories and the Lib Dems decided to make ordinary people pay for a crash caused by bankers who we bailed out.

https://inews.co.uk/news/politics/question-time-tory-government-has-blood-on-their-hands-over-treatment-of-disabled-people-says-francesca-martinez/

Is it true that the spending policies known collectively as “austerity” have caused the death of over 130,000 people?

Comment: Starting point: https://fullfact.org/health/130000-preventable-deaths-austerity/

Comment: @richardb That points to the paragraph at the bottom of page 6 of https://www.ippr.org/files/2019-06/public-health-and-prevention-june19.pdf#page=8 which says "Moreover, after years of improvements that curbed the overall impact of preventable disease, progress has started to reverse. Between 1990 and 2012 the number of disability-adjusted life years (DALYs), where a preventable risk factor was an underlying cause, fell from 7.7 million to 5.6 million. By 2017, this had once again risen to 5.9 million (IHME 2019)..."

Comment: "... A similar trend is also observed for deaths attributable to a preventable risk factor. Had the trend from 1990 and 2012 continued, we estimate that there could have been 130,000 deaths averted between 2012 and 2017"  so does not point to many additional deaths but more to a flattening of a previously declining trend

Comment: Self-closing as a duplicate - whoops, sorry.